# PowerShell script not running as scheduled task

Tags: powershell

I have the following PS script:

```
$folder = "\\vwhd01\shared\zip_files" # Monitor FTP folder with incoming .
$filter = "*.zip"  # Filter for zip files.
$destination = "T:\Deleteme" #Output for uncompressed files

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}


Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $name -DestinationPath "T:\Deleteme" 
    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green }


# To stop the monitoring, run the following commands:
# Unregister-Event FileCreated
```

This script runs as intended from the PS command line: When a new file is created at specified shared network location, it unzips this file to the target folder.
However, if I run the script as a scheduled task, nothing happens.

I'm scheduling it with the following options:

```
General:
-Run with highest privileges
Trigger:
-Program/Script: powershell
-Arguments: -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file F:\ps\WatchFiles.ps1
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: What does the event history reveal? Does it stop immediately on launch, or is it actually running?

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks for asking. It keeps running, without any error in task history, but neither files are decompressed on cretion.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen If I run from command line "powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file F:\ps\WatchFiles.ps1" nothing happens either.

Comment: Does double-clicking your file open notepad?

Comment: @NekoMusume Yes, it does.. What does it mean, apart that ps1 extension is associated to notepad in registry?

Comment: Try running `ftype Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "%1"` in administrator command prompt. That means that the default opening method of ps scripts is to open in notepad, try the ftype command and then try running the file again with task scheduler

Comment: @NekoMusume Thanks, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does the user running the scheduled task have access to the `T:\Deleteme` output path? Does a mapping to the `T:\` drive exist for that user? Why use a mapping at all and not a UNC path for output?

Comment: @Theo Source folder is a network share, destination folder is a local disc. I'm testing the script with my own account, and I have permission on both locations.